# How to add icon of C++ in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, material-ui

I was making a project in ReactJs for which I needed too include some icons of different Languages and Tools.
In case of Python Icon i did:

```
  <ListItem>
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
      <span
        className="iconify"
        data-icon="simple-icons:python"
        data-inline="false"
        style={{ fontSize: "2rem" }}
      />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      primary="Python"
      classes={{ primary: classes.listItemText }}
    />
  </ListItem>
```

[And I got the this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WH8p5.png)

Where ListItem was imported from Material-Ui

but when I do the same for C++:

```
      <ListItem>
        <ListItemIcon className={classes.icon}>
          <span
            className="iconify"
            data-icon="simple-icons: C++"
            data-inline="false"
            fontSize={{ fontSize: "2.4rem" }}
          />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText
          primary="C++"
          classes={{ primary: classes.listItemText }}
        />
      </ListItem>
```

[I only Get C++ written and not the Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNXhH.png)

What an I doing wrong here? How can I Get C++ icon [Without using an image(.jpg/.png file)]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What icon set are you using ? Could it be that extra spacing in `simple-icons: C++` ?

Comment: It's an icons-pack in react (react-simple-icons). And spacing doesn't matter, it wouldn't change the output. The correct statement should be ```data-icon="simple-icons:cplusplus"```

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement should be:

```
data-icon="simple-icons:cplusplus"
```

****cplusplus instead of C++****

Answer (score -1):

import { SiCplusplus } from "react-icons/si";

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35708394)